# Function with an associative array to check with a conditional PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, conditional-statements

I am making a small game that will display a card only if the suit and number match the randomly selected number and suite. the code is as follows:

```
<?php



$suite['heart'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$suite['spade'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$suite['diamond'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$suite['club'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);

    $suit1 = array_rand($suite);
    $suit2 = array_rand($suite); 

    $card1 = array_rand($suite[$suit1]);
    $card2 = array_rand($suite[$suit2]);

    $card_1 = $suite[$suit1][$card1];
    $card_2 = $suite[$suit2][$card2];

    function jqk($n){
            if($n == 11 && $suit1 == 'club'){
                  return "<img src='img/clubs_J.png'>";
                } else{
                  return "J";
                }


            else if ($n==12){
                return 'Q';
            }
            else if ($n==13){
                return 'K';
            } else {
            return $n;
            }
        }

    if($card_1 <= $card_2){
            $lowcard = $card_1;
            print "The Low Card is ".jqk($lowcard)."<br />";
        } elseif ($card_1 >= $card_2){
            $highcard = $card_1;

            print "The High Card ".jqk($highcard)."<br />";
        }

        if($card_1 <= $card_2){
            $highcard = $card_2;

            print "The High Card is ".jqk($highcard)."<br />";
        } elseif ($card_1 >= $card_2){
            $lowcard = $card_2;

            print "The Low Card ".jqk($lowcard)."<br />";
        }

?>
```

my problem is that, the output bypasses the check for the $suit1 and all the numbers that match 11 displays the image. thank you in advance

Comment: Having both `1` and `13` to represent the `A` doesn't seem right...

Comment: $suit1 is not defined inside the function

Comment: I just added global $suit1; and the problem continues

Comment: @iplayjumanji2 consider passing that as a param, instead of making changing the scope to `global` which will lead to further problems if you are not aware of what exactly global does

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your `jqk()` function. I wonder how can you even run that function. It has a syntax error here

```
else if ($n==12){ //else pops in without if
```

Try this instead:

```
function jqk($n){
      global $suit1;            
      if( $n == 11 ){
        if( $suit1 == 'club' ){
          return "<img src='img/clubs_J.png'>";
        } else{                
          return "J";
        }
      } else if ( $n == 12 ){
        return 'Q';
      } else if ( $n == 13 ){
        return 'K';
      } else {
        return $n;
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and it is still not matching 'club' and automatically continues to display the image regardless of what suite is randomly generated

Comment: hmmm..working fine for me. Would you please recheck by clearing your cache.